# Java label and break error

Tags: java

Here's the code after Joachim's solution:

http://codepad.org/AB2gu59t

Here are the errors I get now:

> Scripts\OHDHerblaw.java:109: error: undefined label: label1084
>           if (getInventoryCount(new int[] { this.Herb }) == 0) if (getInventoryCou nt(new int[] { this.Unfinished }) == 0) if
>   (getInventoryCount(new int[] { this.I dentified }) == 0) break
>   label417;  if (getInventoryCount(new int[] { this.Vials  }) != 0) if
>   (getInventoryCount(new int[] { this.Identified }) != 0) { if (getIn
>   ventoryCount(new int[] { this.Vials }) != 0) if (getInventoryCount(new
>   int[] { t his.Identified }) != 0) break label1084; if
>   (getInventoryCount(new int[] { this. Unfinished }) != 0)
>
> Scripts\OHDHerblaw.java:110: error: undefined label: label1084
>                 break label1084; }
>
> Scripts\OHDHerblaw.java:201: error: undefined label: label1391
>                   break label1391;
>
> Scripts\OHDHerblaw.java:202: error: undefined label: label1706
>           if (getInventoryCount(new int[] { this.Vials }) != 0) if (getInventoryCo unt(new int[] { this.Identified }) != 0) { if
>   (getInventoryCount(new int[] { thi s.Vials }) != 0) if
>   (getInventoryCount(new int[] { this.Identified }) != 0) brea k
>   label1706; if (getInventoryCount(new int[] { this.Unfinished }) != 0)
>
> Scripts\OHDHerblaw.java:203: error: undefined label: label1706
>                 break label1706; }
>
> 5 errors

I'm not sure how to define the labels.

Well after some struggle, I got it to work. Here's the modified code if anyone's interested.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class OHDHerblaw extends Script {

   int Herb;
   int Identified = 0;
   int Unfinished;
   int Ingrediant;
   int potsMade;
   int Vials = 464;
   int[] POTARRAY = new int[]{222, 474, 477, 480, 483, 486, 489, 492, 495, 498, 566, 569, 570};
   int[] UNIDARRAY = new int[0];
   int[] IDARRAY = new int[0];
   boolean onlyId = false;
   boolean idHerbs = false;
   boolean isMixing = false;
   boolean unfinishedOnly = false;


   public OHDHerblaw(Extension var1) {
      super(var1);
   }

   public void init(String var1) {
      String[] var2 = var1.trim().replaceAll(" ", "").split(",");
      if(!var2[0].equals("")) {
         this.Herb = Integer.parseInt(var2[0]);
         if(this.Herb <= 443) {
            if(this.Herb == 165 || this.Herb >= 435 && this.Herb <= 443) {
               this.idHerbs = true;
               this.unfinishedOnly = false;
               if(this.Herb == 165) {
                  this.Identified = 444;
                  this.Unfinished = 454;
               } else if(this.Herb > 165) {
                  this.Identified = this.Herb + 10;
                  this.Unfinished = this.Herb + 20;
               }
            }
         } else if(this.Herb >= 444) {
            if(this.Herb >= 444 && this.Herb <= 453) {
               this.Herb -= 10;
               this.Identified = this.Herb + 10;
               this.Unfinished = this.Herb + 20;
               this.idHerbs = false;
               this.unfinishedOnly = false;
            } else if(this.Herb >= 454 && this.Herb <= 463) {
               this.Herb -= 20;
               this.Identified = this.Herb + 10;
               this.Unfinished = this.Herb + 20;
               this.idHerbs = false;
               this.unfinishedOnly = true;
            }
         } else {
            System.out.println("That\'s is not a valid Herb Id...");
            this.stopScript();
         }
      }

      if(!var2[1].equals("")) {
         this.Ingrediant = Integer.parseInt(var2[1]);
         if(this.Ingrediant != 270 && this.Ingrediant != 473 && this.Ingrediant != 220 && this.Ingrediant != 219 && this.Ingrediant != 471 && this.Ingrediant != 469 && this.Ingrediant != 472 && this.Ingrediant != 501) {
            System.out.println("No ingredient selected. We will not be making full potions...");
            this.Ingrediant = 0;
            this.isMixing = false;
         } else {
            this.isMixing = true;
         }
      }

      if(this.unfinishedOnly && !this.isMixing) {
         System.out.println("Not possible, please re-check script setup...");
         this.stopScript();
      }

   }

   public int main() {

      if(this.getFatigue() >= 90) {
         this.useSleepingBag();
         return this.random(800, 1000);
      } else {
         if(!this.onlyId) {
            int[] var1;
            if(this.isMixing) {
               if(this.idHerbs && this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Herb}) > 0) {
                  this.useItem(this.getInventoryIndex(new int[]{this.Herb}));
                  return this.random(200, 350);
               }

               if(this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Identified}) > 0 && this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Vials}) > 0 && this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Herb}) == 0) {
                  this.useItemWithItem(this.getInventoryIndex(new int[]{this.Identified}), this.getInventoryIndex(new int[]{this.Vials}));
                  return this.random(200, 350);
               }

               if(this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Ingrediant}) > 0 && this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Unfinished}) > 0) {
                  this.useItemWithItem(this.getInventoryIndex(new int[]{this.Ingrediant}), this.getInventoryIndex(new int[]{this.Unfinished}));
                  return this.random(500, 600);
               }

               if(this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Herb}) == 0 && this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Unfinished}) == 0 && this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Identified}) == 0 || this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Vials}) == 0 || this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Identified}) == 0 || (this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Vials}) == 0 || this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Identified}) == 0) && this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Unfinished}) == 0) {
                  if(this.isQuestMenu()) {
                     this.answer(0);
                     return this.random(2000, 3000);
                  }

                  if(this.isBanking()) {
                     int var2;
                     if(this.unfinishedOnly) {
                        if(this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Ingrediant}) == 0 || this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Unfinished}) == 0) {
                           for(var2 = 0; var2 < this.POTARRAY.length; ++var2) {
                              if(this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.POTARRAY[var2]}) > 0) {
                                 this.deposit(this.POTARRAY[var2], this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.POTARRAY[var2]}));
                                 return this.random(1250, 1500);
                              }
                           }
                        }

                        if(this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Unfinished}) == 0) {
                           this.withdraw(this.Unfinished, 14);
                           return this.random(1500, 2000);
                        }

                        if(this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Ingrediant}) == 0 && this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Unfinished}) > 0) {
                           this.withdraw(this.Identified, this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Unfinished}));
                           return this.random(1500, 2000);
                        }

                        this.closeBank();
                        return this.random(200, 300);
                     }

                     if(!this.unfinishedOnly) {
                        if(this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Ingrediant}) == 0 || this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Unfinished}) == 0) {
                           for(var2 = 0; var2 < this.POTARRAY.length; ++var2) {
                              if(this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.POTARRAY[var2]}) > 0) {
                                 this.deposit(this.POTARRAY[var2], this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.POTARRAY[var2]}));
                                 return this.random(1250, 1500);
                              }
                           }
                        }

                        if(this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Unfinished}) > 0) {
                           this.withdraw(this.Ingrediant, this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Unfinished}));
                           this.closeBank();
                           return this.random(2000, 3000);
                        }

                        if(this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Vials}) == 0) {
                           this.withdraw(this.Vials, 14);
                           return this.random(1000, 1500);
                        }

                        if(this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Herb}) == 0 && this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Unfinished}) == 0 && this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Identified}) == 0 && this.idHerbs) {
                           this.withdraw(this.Herb, 14);
                           return this.random(2000, 3000);
                        }

                        if(this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Identified}) == 0) {
                           this.withdraw(this.Identified, 14);
                           return this.random(1000, 1500);
                        }

                        this.closeBank();
                        return this.random(1000, 1500);
                     }
                  }

                  var1 = this.getNpcByIdNotTalk(this.BANKERS);
                  if(var1[0] != -1 && !this.isBanking() && !this.isQuestMenu() && this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Ingrediant}) == 0) {
                     this.talkToNpc(var1[0]);
                     return this.random(3250, 3500);
                  }
               }
            }

            if(!this.isMixing) {
               if(this.idHerbs && this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Herb}) > 0) {
                  this.useItem(this.getInventoryIndex(new int[]{this.Herb}));
                  return this.random(200, 350);
               }

               if(this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Identified}) > 0 && this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Vials}) > 0 && this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Herb}) == 0) {
                  this.useItemWithItem(this.getInventoryIndex(new int[]{this.Identified}), this.getInventoryIndex(new int[]{this.Vials}));
                  return this.random(200, 350);
               }

               if(this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Herb}) == 0 && this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Unfinished}) == 0 && this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Vials}) == 0 && this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Identified}) == 0 || this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Vials}) == 0 || this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Identified}) == 0 || (this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Vials}) == 0 || this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Identified}) == 0) && this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Unfinished}) == 0) {
                  if(this.isQuestMenu()) {
                     this.answer(0);
                     return this.random(2000, 3000);
                  }

                  if(this.isBanking()) {
                     if(this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Herb}) == 0 && this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Unfinished}) == 0 && this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Vials}) == 0 && this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Identified}) == 0 && this.idHerbs) {
                        this.withdraw(this.Herb, 14);
                        return this.random(2000, 3000);
                     }

                     if(this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Unfinished}) > 0) {
                        this.deposit(this.Unfinished, this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Unfinished}));
                        return this.random(200, 300);
                     }

                     if(this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Vials}) == 0) {
                        this.withdraw(this.Vials, 14);
                        return this.random(1000, 1500);
                     }

                     if(this.getInventoryCount(new int[]{this.Identified}) == 0) {
                        this.withdraw(this.Identified, 14);
                        return this.random(1000, 1500);
                     }

                     this.closeBank();
                     return this.random(1000, 1500);
                  }

                  var1 = this.getNpcByIdNotTalk(this.BANKERS);
                  if(var1[0] != -1 && !this.isBanking() && !this.isQuestMenu()) {
                     this.talkToNpc(var1[0]);
                     return this.random(3500, 3750);
                  }
               }
            }
         }

         return this.random(200, 300);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please don't re-write your entire question after one step has been solved. Either *append* the new information to the question or ask a separate question, if it's significantly different from your original one. But this way you won't leave any meaningful question for people who search for solutions later on (and *those* are the majority of SO users).

Comment: I tried to append many times but it kept telling me I had the wrong indents in the code which is why I ended up putting it in codepad. Regarding the code, just so I and others can understand, why does it come up as undefined if the labels are defined?

Answer (score 2):

A label can only be [used before a statement (JLS §14.7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.7).

A local variable declaration is not a statement (in JLS-speak it's [a "block statement" (JLS §14.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2), which is a super-set of statement).

Simple move your `int[] arrayOfInt;` to the line *before* the label and you should be good:

```
int[] arrayOfInt;
label417:
if (this.isMixing) {
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks Joachim that solved the original error but I'm still getting some undefined label errors. It is decompiled code as you suggested.

Comment: @ColiseSanders: my advise for compiling decompiled code: don't do it. First: it's a pain from a technical point of view. Second: it's *usually* not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

A label must be followed by a **statement**. In your code, it's followed by a variable declaration, which is not a statement.

Move the label after the variable declaration:

```
int[] arrayOfInt;

label417:
if (this.isMixing) {
    // ...
```

By the way, I regard using labels in Java code as a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) - something that indicates that there's something wrong with the design of the code. A label is like a [goto statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto), which is an infamous construction that makes code hard to understand (it leads to [spaghetti code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)).

Instead of using labels, use other control structures such as `for` or `while` loops.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this code is the result of some decompilation. No human uses labels named "label417".

Comment: @JoachimSauer Could be, but regardless, people shouldn't use labels in their source code.

Answer (score 1):

@Joachim's answer has nailed it.

I just want to explain WHY ...

A `break <label>` statement can only break *out* to an *enclosing* statement in the current method that has the given label.  A local variable declaration cannot include a `break` statement.  Therefore a `label` on a local variable declaration cannot be broken too.

I suspect that you were trying to use the `break <label>` statement like a C / C++ `goto` statement.  It doesn't work that way.  Even if a label was allowed there, you wouldn't be able to break to it.  For instance, this is equally wrong:

```
label: if (i == 1) {
   // so something
}
if (i == 2) {
   break label;  // compilation error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Label on assignment has a bit different syntax:

```
 int i;
 label12: i = 42; // label on the assignment
```

If you are assigning value to a label you have to define it first.

In your case, change the code to:

```
if (!this.onlyId)
    {
      int[] arrayOfInt;
      label417:      
      if (this.isMixing)
      {
        if (this.idHerbs) {
          if (getInventoryCount(new int[] { this.Herb }) > 0) {
            useItem(getInventoryIndex(new int[] { this.Herb }));
            return random(200, 350);
          }
        }
```